# How to compute every cell of a confusion matrix manually and individually given the ytrue, and ytest arrays without sklearn?

Tags: python, arrays, loops, confusion-matrix

How to compute every cell individually of a confusion matrix manually given the ytrue, and ytest arrays to double check that the confusion matrix created is correct? Is there already a library to do this or do you have to program it?

Suppose you had `ytrue=[1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3] and ytest=[1,1,1,1,3,3,1,1,2,3,3,2,2].`

How do you loop through the cells to compute the (ith,jth) entry manually.

I don't mean create the matrix. I mean give me the (i,j) coordinate of the matrix, individually by looping, or is there a package we may find to do it?

Comment: To get the value for any coordinates in the confusion matrix, you need to iterate through the whole data anyways. You can use `sklearn` library to get the confusion matrix.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/95d4f0841/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py#L196) is the link to `sklearn`'s `confusion_matrix` function's source code

Comment: How do you do it without sklearn? Suppose sklearn is not allowed.

Comment: Please share the code you've tried and let us know what the issues are if you want to do it manually.